# Proxying between tomcat and apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-applications, proxy

I have apache2 and tomcat7 in /var/lib/tomcat7. I have my two apps in tomcat webapps: app1 and app2. I have configured my apache virtual host as below:

#

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myweb1.com

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/web1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/web1/
```

```
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all

 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

#

myweb1.com is running in a browser but when I make another vhost for web2, myweb2.com is not loading. Yet when I do myweb2:8080/web2 in my browser it's loading the page. What could be the reason for this? Note that myweb2.com has no problem with DNS entry.
I have tried to put web2 into /opt/tomcat9/webapps but the same results come.

Comment: Please show the complete apache config.   Adding a 2nd entry on the same port [80] isn't going to work.....

Comment: change to this : ProxyPass /web1/ http://localhost:8080/web1/ + ProxyPass /web2 http://localhost:8080/web2/ (with 2 similar proxypassreverse), or only ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ (and one proxypassreverse)

Comment: @EugèneAdell I tried that but not working

Comment: @BretWeinraub I failed to paste my apache2.conf here. The text is too long. However I am simply using default setings. What do you mean by this " Adding a 2nd entry on the same port [80] isn't going to work" ? What should I do?

Comment: @Innocento You need to read how work [name-based Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/name-based.html) . The solution is around 2 virtual hosts, each one with its proxypass and reverse

Comment: @EugèneAdell I am using two different vitual hosts

Comment: This is not what we see in your config.

Comment: @EugèneAdell,  I just posted one vhost but the second is also similar to that one except the app name and doman name.

Comment: @Innocento Post them anyway.

Comment: Try a gist on github.com

Comment: @BretWeinraub What is it? Can you tell me more?

Comment: you can push your apache conf there and then link to it: https://gist.github.com/